# A question concerning cyclic property of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

> For which $n$ is the group $U_n$ (group of all positive integers less than $n$ that are coprime to $n$) a cyclic group?

Comment: $n=2,4,p^k,2p^k$($p$ is an odd prime number)

Comment: Please register. It helps you to track your posts easily for the future.

Answer (score 1):

$U_n$ is cyclic if and only if there is a *[primitive root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n)* mod $n$. We know that the positive integers $n$ for which there are primitive roots are $n = 2, \,4, \,p^k, \text { and }\,2p^k,\;$ where $p$ is an odd prime.

Comment: Needs another TU +1!